# Convert $x^2 + y^2 = xy$ into the form $f(x) = y$ OR $f(y) = x$?

Tags: functions

How should I take all the "x" elements free from y , in order to form a "function of x" or a " function of y " ?

Is this even possible ?

Comment: Is x*y representing multiplication? What happens when you solve this as a quadratic in $x$?

Comment: Yes , it does mean multiplication .

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is possible only iff $x=y=0$:

$$x^2-xy+y^2 =0\implies 2x^2-2xy+2y^2=0$$
so $$(x-y)^2+x^2+y^2=0\implies x=y=0$$

So if you take a function $f(x)=x$ then $f(y) =x$.

Comment: What if $x$ and $y$ are not necessarily real?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut then we have a (new) problem. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 + y^2 = xy$$
$$~y^2 - x.y +x^2 = 0$$
$$~y = \frac {1 ± i√3}{2} x$$
$$~y = f(x)$$

Comment: Be carefull .....